# System of equations for vector span

Tags: vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

If I have a system of equations derived from $(x, y, 3x-y)=a(1,2,1)+b(1,1,1)$

$\begin{align}
a+b&=x\\
2a+b&=y\\
a+2b&=3x-y\\
\end{align}$

I substitute $b$ ($b=x-a$) from first equation for $b$ in other equations, to get a general solution of $a=y-x$

Does this sound correct, or have I gone wrong somewhere?

Comment: what is given here?

Comment: Shouldn't the last equation of the system by $a+b=3x-y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plugging $x=a+b$ and $y=2a+b$ in your last equation we get $a+2b=a+2b$ and this is true.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/933682)

Comment: do you know more than i do